# class variable access within recursive function

Tags: c++, class, variables, recursion

for an intro program, we were asked to build a program that could find every single possible working magic square of a given size. I am having trouble modifying a class variable from within a recursive function. I am trying to increment the number of magic squares found every time the combination of numbers I am trying yields a magic square.

More specifically, I am trying to modify numSquares within the function recursiveMagic(). After setting a breakpoint at that specific line, the variable, numSquares does not change, even though I am incrementing it. I think it has something to do with the recursion, however, I am not sure. If you want to lend some advice, I appreciate it.

```
//============================================================================
// Name        : magicSquare.cpp
// Author      : 
// Version     :
// Copyright   : Your copyright notice
// Description : Hello World in C++, Ansi-style
//============================================================================

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/**
 * MagicSquare
 */
class MagicSquare {
private:
    int magicSquare[9];
    int usedNumbers[9];
    int numSquares;
    int N;
    int magicInt;
public:

    MagicSquare() {
        numSquares = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            usedNumbers[i] = 0;
        N = 3; //default is 3
        magicInt = N * (N * N + 1) / 2;
    }

    MagicSquare(int n) {
        numSquares = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            usedNumbers[i] = 0;
        N = n;
        magicInt = N * (N * N + 1) / 2;
    }

    void recursiveMagic(int n) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= N * N + 1; i++) {
            if (usedNumbers[i - 1] == 0) {
                usedNumbers[i - 1] = 1;
                magicSquare[n] = i;
                if (n < N * N)
                    recursiveMagic(n + 1);
                else {
                    if (isMagicSquare()) {
                        numSquares++; //this is the line that is not working correctly
                        printSquare();
                    }
                }
                usedNumbers[i - 1] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    //To efficiently check all rows and collumns, we must convert the one dimensional array into a 2d array
    //since the sudo 2d array looks like this:
    //        0 1 2
    //        3 4 5
    //        6 7 8
    //the following for-if loops convert the i to the appropriate location.

    bool isMagicSquare() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if ((magicSquare[i * 3] + magicSquare[i * 3 + 1] + magicSquare[i * 3 + 2]) != magicInt) //check horizontal
                return false;
            else if ((magicSquare[i] + magicSquare[i + 3] + magicSquare[i + 6]) != magicInt) // check vertical
                return false;
        }
        if ((magicSquare[0] + magicSquare[4] + magicSquare[8]) != magicInt)
            return false;
        if ((magicSquare[6] + magicSquare[4] + magicSquare[2]) != magicInt)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * printSquare: prints the current magic square combination
     */
    void printSquare() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            cout << magicSquare[i * 3] << " " << magicSquare[i * 3 + 1]
                << " " << magicSquare[i * 3 + 2] << endl;
        cout << "------------------" << endl;
    }

    /**
     * checkRow: checks to see if the current row will complete the magic square
     * @param i - used to determine what row is being analyzed
     * @return true if it is a working row, and false if it is not
     */
    bool checkRow(int i) {
        i = (i + 1) % 3 - 1;
        return (magicSquare[i * 3] + magicSquare[i * 3 + 1] + magicSquare[i * 3 + 2]) == magicInt;
    }

    int getnumSquares() {
        return numSquares;
    }
}; //------End of MagicSquare Class-----

int main() {
    MagicSquare square;
    cout << "Begin Magic Square recursion:" << endl << "------------------"
            << endl;
    square.recursiveMagic(0);
    cout << "Done with routine, returned combinations: " << square.getnumSquares() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you narrow it down?

Comment: We're not going to do your homework for you.

Comment: Did you try different expressions such as numsquares+=1 or++numsquares or numsquares= numsquares+1 etc...I know but just try that first.

Comment: Also try all that but with debug and release builds and so on.

Comment: But no recursion cannot be the problem since each time it calls the recursion it passes the same class instance therefore it touches the same field. Also try one other thing is make that function not inline. I know but again just try it.

Comment: Lastly probably not the thing but just try use 128 for the array sizes just be extra sure it is not overwriting memory. If that is not it then set it back to 9.

Comment: Yeah I think your array indexes are wrong. You are overwriting memory. Try 10 for the array sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is being overwritten leading to overwriting the numSquares field.

```
class MagicSquare {
private:
    int magicSquare[9];
    int usedNumbers[9];
```

Changes to

```
class MagicSquare {
private:
    int magicSquare[10];
    int usedNumbers[10];
```

Also in your initializer the loop says < 9 but what you want to say is < 10. Or just use memset is better for that purpose.

Comment: Hello, the array size was definitely it. Thanks for the advice! I would plus one you if I could..

Comment: Can you not just accept the answer? I don't know, never asked a question before.